# how do put latex code in a kable caption?

Tags: latex, kableextra

I would like to put the following latex code into a Kable caption.

`Table 1. From what university did you receive your educator licensure program preparation? (\textit{n}=147)`

Comment: Can you add some code of what you tried and which problem you face?

Comment: Wild guess: `\\textit{n} = 147` or `$n = 147$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
knitr::kable('no data is provided',
             caption = 'From what university did you receive your educator 
             licensure program preparation? $(\\textit{n}=147)$',
             format = 'html')
```